# Encoding Ordinal Values in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm trying to encode Ordinal Categorical Values in the 3rd column of my dataset where "Tiny Mongra" has the lowest value and "1st Wand" has the highest values. It is synonymous to using small, medium and large sizes where the current dataset denotes the size of  a grain of rice.

I keep getting the following error when I run this snippet:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-ae4501cc0ac1>", line 19, in <module>
    X[:, 2] = ordinalencoder_X_3.fit_transform(X[:, 2])

  File "/Users/anhad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 462, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)

  File "/Users/anhad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py", line 794, in fit
    self._fit(X)

  File "/Users/anhad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py", line 61, in _fit
    X = self._check_X(X)

  File "/Users/anhad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py", line 47, in _check_X
    X_temp = check_array(X, dtype=None)

  File "/Users/anhad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 552, in check_array
    "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=['1st Wand' '1st Wand' '1st Wand' ... '1st Wand' '1st Wand' '1st Wand'].
```

On further inspection, I have found that the error was not warning me about the list of categorical data, but was referring to the column that I wanted encoded. For some reason it considers that column a 1D array of the form:

```
array=['1st Wand' '1st Wand' '1st Wand' '1st Wand' '1st Wand' 'Dubar' '2nd Wand'
 'Tibar' 'Mongra' '1st Wand' '1st Wand' '1st Wand' '1st Wand' '1st Wand'
 '1st Wand' '2nd Wand' 'Super Dubar' 'Super Tibar' ... '1st Wand' '1st Wand'].
```

This is weird since I am using LabelEncoder to fit_transform other categorical values in my dataset and they work fine.

Here is a link to the Data. See "Data" sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12nAU5QztVnVroRYDsRDsZGUyBpBTwAD5yMmbMaAxnHQ/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the full code. Refer to the last part:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Ryze Price NN Data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:7].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 7].values

# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder, OrdinalEncoder

labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 0])

labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 1])

# SEE THIS PART
category_array = ["Tiny Mongra","Mini Mongra","Mongra","Super Mongra","Mini Dubar","Dubar","Super Dubar","Mini Tibar","Tibar","Super Tibar","2nd Wand","Super 2nd Wand","1st Wand"]
ordinalencoder_X_3 = OrdinalEncoder(categories=category_array)
X[:, 2] = ordinalencoder_X_3.fit_transform(np.array(X[:,2])
```

I expect that categorical data is encoded as follows:
"Tiny Mongra" should be encoded as 0
.
.
"1st Wand" should be encoded as 12

Answer (score 5):

The main distinction between `LabelEncoder` and `OrdinalEncoder` is their purpose:

- `LabelEncoder` should be used for **target** variables,
- `OrdinalEncoder` should be used for **feature** variables.

In general they work the same, but:

- `LabelEncoder` needs *y: array-like of shape [n_samples]*,
- `OrdinalEncoder` needs *X: array-like, shape [n_samples, n_features]*.

If you just want to encode your categorical variable's values to `0, 1, ..., n`, use `LabelEncoder` the same way you did with X1 and X2.

```
labelencoder_X_3 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_3.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
```

But I would transform all three variables with `OrdinalEncoder` at the same time:

```
ordinalencoder_X = OrdinalEncoder()
X[:, 0:3] = ordinalencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 0:3])
```

Comment: I wanted to use Ordinal Encoder because I wanted to decide the order of relation between the categories where Tiny Mongra<Mini Mongra ... 2nd Wand < 1st Wand. It is imperative that "1st Wand" gets assigned the highest order and not some random number based on its order of appearance in the data. The other columns are just categories with no relation to each other, but this column requires an ordinal relation. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this passing `mapping=[{‘col’: ‘col_name’, ‘mapping’: [('Tiny Mongra', 0), (‘Mini Mongra’, 1), ... , (‘1st Wan’, 12)]}]` as a parameter to `OrdinalEncoder()`. `col_name` should be a name of column you're encoding.

Comment: `ordinalencoder_X_3 = OrdinalEncoder(mapping = cut_mapping)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-d266fd327d1f>", line 1, in <module>
    ordinalencoder_X_3 = OrdinalEncoder(mapping = cut_mapping)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mapping'`

Comment: where cut_mapping is the variable that stores this list

Comment: I just have a thought here. Why do we need ordinal encoder to do this task? We can directly replace categories with the numbers(Give that mapping in some dictionary) using Apply function in Pandas.

Comment: How would that be implemented?

Comment: Adding it as an answer. Hope that will help!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Ordinal Encoder, One other option is to use Pandas Applymap function and pass the mapping dictionary using Lambda Function.

Here is the mapping dictionary:

```
mapping = { "Tiny Mongra" : 0,"Mini Mongra" : 1,"Mongra":2,"Super Mongra" : 3,"Mini 
Dubar":4,"Dubar":5,"Super Dubar":6,"Mini Tibar":7,"Tibar":8,"Super Tibar":9,"2nd 
Wand":10,"Super 2nd Wand" :11,"1st Wand":12}
```

Lets say below is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['Tiny Mongra', 'Mini Dubar' ,'Mongra', '1st Wand' ,'1st Wand' 
,'Dubar' ,'2nd Wand','Tibar', 'Mongra', 'Super Dubar', '1st Wand', '1st Wand', '1st 
 Wand' ,'1st Wand','1st Wand', '2nd Wand' ,'Super Dubar' ,'Super Tibar' ,'1st Wand', 
'1st Wand'],   columns = ['category'])
```

Then you can create another encoded mapping column using below code:

```
df['mapped_category'] = df.applymap(lambda x : mapping[x])
```

Comment: I get `KeyError` when I try this. Any ideas?

Comment: check the dictionary if there is any missing key. For example: your dataframe may have a value 'XYZ' but your dictionary doesnt contain its mapping like  XYZ:123

Comment: Old, but you can also do df.apply(lambda x: ['Tiny Mongra', 'Mini Mongra', 'Mongra', 'Super Mongra',....].index(x))

Answer (score 0):

Try using below;

ordinalencoder_X = OrdinalEncoder()
X[:, 0:3] = ordinalencoder_X.fit_transform([X[:, 0:3]])

Comment: Try using below.

ordinalencoder_X = OrdinalEncoder()
X[:, 0:3] = ordinalencoder_X.fit_transform(pd.DataFrame(X.iloc[:, 0:3]))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please edit your answer and add details like what the above code do and how it helps to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below.

ordinalencoder_X = OrdinalEncoder()
X[:, 0:3] = ordinalencoder_X.fit_transform(pd.DataFrame(X.iloc[:, 0:3]))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).